# not able to ping server or but can RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, ping, windows-server-2012

Im on Windows Server 2012 and earlier today I stopped being able to connect to my website. I tried to connect to RDP to check the error log. I could connect and login, but the error log was empty.

I pinged the server but I was unable to reach it.... strange.

I **AM** able to RDP into the server.

I **AM** able to connect to the server's VPN

I am **NOT** able to connect to my website

I am **NOT** able to ping the system

ICMP echo is enabled on the server.

Comment: So, are you saying that, normally, you _can_ ping the server?

Comment: You say ICMP echo is enabled. Have you checked the firewall settings since this happened? I'm not doubting you so much as I'm doubting Windows.

Comment: @Scott Yes, normally I am able to ping the server

Comment: @r.tanner.f The custom rule 'Ping' is enabled. Here is its config: Under protocols and Ports: Protocol type = ICMPv4. Customize: All ICMP Types selected

Comment: I also ran the netsh command to enable ping

Answer (score 3):

It is possible the local machine is blocking the ICMP response (though this would be particularly unusual) as well as the web content.

Try pinging and opening the web site from a different machine.

For IIS specifically, on the server in the IIS Manager, restart the web site to reset sockets.
You can also restart the Windows Firewall service on the server to ensure it parses open/closed/limited IP/ports correctly.

Comment: Restarted IIS website... Nothing, Different machine... nothing, Restart firewall service... I actually lost the ability to RDP from the public address. Had to switch to the VPNs connection.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I can RDP to my server in LAN, but just failed to ping or access MS SQL Server. Finally I checked firewall setting, it was turned on. Once I turned it off,  everything back to normal. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have the answer. I had NAT enabled for my VPN. that was the last thing I did before I wasnt able to ping. I removed the NAT interface and suddenly I could ping again!

Could somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: You would need to ask it in a new question, but you will need to provide a LOT more detail about your situation as the information we have now is not enough at all to diagnose it.

Answer (score -2):

In my case firewall was ON on RDP server. Because of firewall exceptions we could manage to RDP it, but it wasn't pingable.