# i can't ping but can RDP on my home windows server 2012

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012

I Have a Home Server (Windows Server 2012), where i have wamp, teamspeak, and other servers, i used windows because some of the servers i need are windows based, no change to Linux is not an option

My problem is that i can't not ping to my Server or access for example wamp with an external machine, but before was working great, i didn't change anything, just stop working

the funny thing is that im able to access to RDP, with an external machine
also , i had disabled the firewall, i restart the router, and nothing

i found these links

[not able to ping server or but can RDP](https://superuser.com/questions/531733/not-able-to-ping-server-or-but-can-rdp)

[Not able to ping remote server](https://superuser.com/questions/562343/not-able-to-ping-remote-server?rq=1)

but not luck

any clue why is this happening?

Comment: You may be forwarding a 3389 port (RDP) for example and not forwarding ICMP packets using NAT. Couldn't that be the case? Do you have a router in between our server and machine that initiates the ping request?

Comment: Are you pinging an ipv4 or ipv6 address?

Comment: @JasonBristol ipv4, actually i disabled ipv6 because was causing problem before

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server does not respond to ping requests by default.
A quick Googling guides me to this guide: http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/11/20/how-to-enable-ping-in-windows-server-2012/
If you are unable to access your WAMP server, I would suggest you first check if the web server is running.
If your server is sitting behind a LAN, check for internal connectivity within the LAN. Open a web browser, and navigate to the server's IP.
Third, make sure that proper ports are opened in your router. Most home routers has a function named "port forwarding" or "virtual server" to do this.

Comment: Yeap, i checked that link you mentioned before, but not luck, also i disabled the firewall, i'm able to access in LAN, yeap and i remap the port forwading on the router and restart, but the problem still persist